# Highlight a matching regex in in a text input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have a working code that tests regex : highlight a matching regex.
But my problem is that i want to highlight the result in the same input as the string to test. 
Please find below the html and js and two pics that describes the result that i got and the expected result..

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="regex" class="span-12 pdg-sm font-lg brd-rad-md" placeholder="Enter your regex" ng-change="applyRegex()">
        <input ng-model="stringToTest" ng-change="applyRegex()" rows="6" class="spdg-sm" ng-bind-html="highlightedResults">
        <pre class="pdg-sm" ng-bind-html="highlightedResults"></pre>
```

**JS:**

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $sce) {
$scope.stringToTest = '';
$scope.applyRegex = function()
{   
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.highlightedResults = '';

        var regex = new RegExp('(' + $scope.regex + ')');
        $scope.results = $scope.stringToTest.match();
        $scope.highlightedResults = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.stringToTest.replace(regex, '<b style="color: #FFF; background-color: green;" class="mrg-xs pdg-xs brd-rad-sm">$1</b>'));
        console.log($scope.highlightedResults);
}}
```

[Result that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t4Qx.png)

[Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcp0s.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[I jsfiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/27564/) the solution you may apply.

Please, note that to change the input text background color, you have to add some CSS. Example :

```
input.green::selection {
  background: green;
  color:white;
}
```

Then, in the solution I used a controller (as you did) :

```
angular.module('testapp', []).controller('TodoCtrl', 

    ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.stringToTest = '';
    $scope.applyRegex = function()
    {   
        $scope.results = [];
        $scope.highlightedResults = '';

            var regex = new RegExp('(' + $scope.regex + ')');
            $scope.results = $scope.stringToTest.match(regex);
            if ($scope.results){
              var firstResult = $scope.results[0];
                document.querySelector("input[name=result]").setSelectionRange(0, (firstResult.length));
            }
    }
    }]);
```

The above code will solve the solution. However, as we are doing some DOM manipulation, it's preferable to do it through a directive.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Zakaria , i don't need to change the input text background color, or maybe i'll do it in the html file

Comment: Hi again @Zakaria , i have a little other problem; after highlighting a result if i add another character the input will be empty.. so how to edit that so i can be able to continue typing anything without setting the input to emty...